# uniform continuity of the function $t\mapsto\langle x^*,f(t)\rangle$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $f:\mathbb{R}\to X$  a function. If we have $t\mapsto\langle x^*,f(t)\rangle$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for each $x^*\in D$ where $D$ is  a dense subset of $X^*$ (dual space of $X$). Do we have $t\mapsto\langle x^*,f(t)\rangle$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for each $x^*\in X^*$. If not can we add an additional assumption to make this true ?

Comment: Presumably you need to add (at least) some form of "uniform uniform-continuity hypothesis", in the sense that there exists a common module of uniform continuity. Without loss of generality, $D$ is a dense supspace of $X^*$. If there exists $\omega:(0,+\infty)\to[0,+\infty)$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in D\cap B_X$, where $B_X$ is the unit ball of $X$, for all $t,t'\in\Bbb R$, $$|t-t'|<\delta\Longrightarrow |x(f(t)-f(t'))|<\epsilon$$ (where $\delta=\omega(\epsilon))$). This may even prove to be sufficient through some application of Hahn Banach. It may (?) be equivalent to $f\dots$

Comment: $\dots$ being uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the passage from a dense subset to everything is not always possible. For example, let $X=\ell^2$ with standard basis $(e_n)$ and define
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(1-n|t-n|)^+ e_n
$$ 
where as usual, $a^+=\max(0,a)$. This is a continuous function.

Let $D=c_{00}$, the set of eventually zero sequences. For every $y\in D$ the function $t\mapsto \langle f(t),y\rangle $ is uniformly continuous, because it is continuous and compactly supported.

On the other hand, for $y=(1/j: j\ge 1)\in \ell^2$ the function 
$$
g(t) = \langle f(t),y\rangle = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (1-n|t-n|)^+ 
$$
is not uniformly continuous because   $|g(n)-g(n+1/n)|=1$, $n=2,3,\dots $.

---

Answer to a misunderstood question: does weak uniform continuity imply uniform continuity of $f$?

No,   even if $D=X^*$. For example, let $X=\ell^2$ with standard basis $(e_n)$ and define
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty (1-n|t-n|)^+ e_n
$$ 
where as usual, $a^+=\max(0,a)$. The function $f$ is not uniformly continuous because $$\|f(n)-f(n+1/n)\|=1,\quad n=2,3,\dots $$
On the other hand, for every $y\in \ell^2$ the function $t\mapsto \langle f(t),y\rangle $ is uniformly continuous, because it is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)=0$.

---

As Olivier Bégassat said in a comment, having *[uniformly equicontinuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity)* functions $t\mapsto \langle x^*, f(t)\rangle$  over a dense subset $D$ of the unit ball of $X^*$  is enough. In fact this is a necessary and sufficient condition for uniform continuity of $f$. The necessity is straightforward. So is the sufficiency; given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta>0$ as in the definition of uniform equicontinuity. Then if $|t_1-t_2|<\delta$, 
$$\| f(t_1)-f(t_2)\| = \sup_{x^*\in D}\langle x^*, f(t_1)-f(t_2)\rangle \le \epsilon$$ as desired.

Comment: Maybe I think you misunderstood my question, I do not want to extend continuity from weak topology to strong topology, my question is: If I have weak uniform continuity for every $x^*$ in a dense subset of $X^*$, can we extend it to all $x^* \in X^*$ ? Thanks for your example anyway, I was planning the other day to ask about such an example, now I have it ;)

Comment: @user144542 I added the answer to the actual question you asked.